# Can't find a path to my xml file

Tags: c#, ios, xml, path

I'm trying to find a my XML file called ClassData.xml, but can't find it. The file itself is hidden in a folder called Data. I don't know how to get to the directory of my project where the file is. I'm using ios simulator.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()     
{       
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    this.lbl_Werkt.Text = "het werkt wtf";

    XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();

    try
    {                
        Doc.Load("/Data/ClassData.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The File could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in Doc.SelectNodes("//Warrior"))
        {
            string Name = node["Name"].InnerText;

            lbl_Name.Text = Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the Data folder a folder inside if your project? are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Data Folder is inside project and I'm using visual studio

Answer (score 0):

For a file in your project, try this:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()     
{       
   base.ViewDidLoad ();

   this.lbl_Werkt.Text = "het werkt wtf";

   try{

      XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
      string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Data\ClassData.xml");

       if(!file.Exists(path))
          throw new IOExpection("File not found");

       Doc.Load(path);

       foreach (XmlNode node in Doc.SelectNodes("//Warrior"))
       {
          string Name = node["Name"].InnerText;

          lbl_Name.Text = Name;
       }
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("The File could not be read:");
       Console.WriteLine(ioEx.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just don't understand how i can't find the folder

Answer (score 0):

I have been really dumb! If someone else has this problem, look at your file (In my case **xml**) and change the build action from **Embedded** to **Content**. If you do this you can just do this:

```
Doc.Load(@"\Data\ClassData.xml");
```